# Publish Jenkins build output to Azure Dev Ops for release pipeline

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I am looking for how to publish a Jenkins build output to Azure Dev Ops for the purpose of deployment.

All of our code is on TFS 2015 and the build definitions are in Jenkins.

We will be migrating to Azure Dev ops completely, but for now I just want to manage the deployment through Dev Ops.  I will script the agent on each of the hosts and move the files to their correct locations.

Looking at the Azure Cli - there [Publish Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-cli#tabpanel_CeZOj-G%20%20Q_azure-cli)

I can't use a service connection to Jenkins because the server is behind a firewall.  I need to be able to publish from Jenkins to Azure Dev Ops.

Any creative ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, you could create a nuget package (or any other package) from jenkins build and push it to the artifacts feed you create in azure devops. Next is to create a release pipeline with a trigger for Azure Artifacts (with enabled continuous integration trigger) for the latest package version.

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/jenkins?view=azure-devops) is an example on how to publish nuget packages from jenkins.

**EDIT**

be aware of the size limitations of Azure Artifacts. As per today, only 2 GB are free of charge.

Comment: I am late responding - but this ended up being the solution.  A decent approach and it works well.